# React(mobx) observer components render() not called when observable changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

In the following sample code, `unfinishedTodoCount` (under `LoadContent` component) is not updated when todo items checked.

I dereference `unfinishedTodoCount` in the render method of TodoListView so i think it must be tracked by mobx.

(I use "trigger rendering" button to force render() to update `unfinishedTodoCount` value.)

**Question:** So, why does not mobx trigger `render()` when `unfinishedTodoCount` changes?

Consideration: I am wondering if `props.children()` is running asynchronously so mobx cannot catch dereferencing.

(Solutions: Various solutions could be applied by uncommenting lines in the code.)

```js
// Uncomment following so render() will be called when unfinishedTodoCount changes.
//@observer
class LoadContent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log("rendering LoadContent");
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children({
          // ...this.props,
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
    @observer
    class TodoListView extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          triggerRender: false
        };
      }
      render() {
        console.log("rendering TodoListView");
        // Uncomment following so render() will be called when unfinishedTodoCount changes.
        //let todoCount = this.props.todoList.unfinishedTodoCount;
        //console.log(todoCount);
        return (
          <div>
            <input
              type="Button"
              onClick={() =>
                this.setState({ triggerRender: !this.state.triggerRender })
              }
              value="Trigger rendering"
            />
            <ul>
              {this.props.todoList.todos.map((todo) => (
                <TodoView todo={todo} key={todo.id} />
              ))}
            </ul>
            <div>
              {/* Uncomment following so render() will be called when unfinishedTodoCount changes. */
              /* {(() => (
                  <div>Tasks left: {this.props.todoList.unfinishedTodoCount}</div>
                ))()} */}
              <LoadContent>
                {() => (
                  <div>Tasks left: {this.props.todoList.unfinishedTodoCount}</div>
                )}
              </LoadContent>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Complete source code here;
https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-mobx-todolist-forked-hep3t?file=/index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think components `render()` is being called asynchronously (yet components are rendered in sync. as expected) per *my proof of concept* below so mobx can not track dereferencing in component.

**Proof of Concept: Components are called async.**

I added a console.log() call after LoadContent and its called before the console.log() in LoadContent.

```js
<LoadContent>
{() => (
  <div>Tasks left: {this.props.todoList.unfinishedTodoCount}</div>
)}
</LoadContent>
{(()=>{console.log("after load content")})()}
```

```
rendering TodoListView 
*after load content* 
rendering LoadContent
```

(Complete source code here; https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-mobx-todolist-forked-hep3t?file=/index.js)

**SOLUTION:** We could use @observer decorator for child components or access those observable variables earlier in `render()` of parent components.

Actually, caveat of `passing renderable callbacks to components` is also stated in following documentation;

> The notable caveat here is passing renderable callbacks to React
> components, take for example the following example:
>
> const MyComponent = observer(({ message }) =>
> <SomeContainer
> title = {() => {message.title}}
> /> )
>
> message.title = "Bar" At first glance everything might seem ok here,
> except that the  is actually not rendered by MyComponent (which
> has a tracked rendering), but by SomeContainer. So to make sure that
> the title of SomeContainer correctly reacts to a new message.title,
> SomeContainer should be an observer as well. If SomeContainer comes
> from an external lib, you can also fix this by wrapping the div in its
> own stateless observer based component, and instantiating that one in
> the callback:
>
> const MyComponent = observer(({ message }) =>
> <SomeContainer
> title = {() => }
> /> )
>
> const TitleRenderer = observer(({ message }) =>
> {message.title}} )
>
> message.title = "Bar"
> https://doc.ebichu.cc/mobx/best/react.html